# Delete visible filtered Rows, Run-time error 1004:Cannot use that command on overlapping selections

Tags: excel, vba

I need to delete visible filtered Rows. 
I got this  `Run-time error 1004: Cannot use that command on overlapping selections`. 
My data has header on first row. 
In advance , greatfull for your help.

```
Sub Macro2()
 
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q6880")
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="0"
    rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please, try `Intersect(ActiveShet.Cells, rng.EntireRow).Delete`. There should be overlapping of the resulted areas, I think.

Comment: I am driving... Please, use 'rng.Offsrt(1)' inside 'Intersect'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some circumstances, filtering creates a discontinuous range with overlapping areas. Please, try the next way, which eliminates these overlappings:

```
Sub MacroDeleteFilteredRows()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:Q6880")
    rng.AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="0"
    Intersect(ActiveSheet.cells, rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Delete
End Sub
```

A error handling for the case of no any visible cells in the filtered range is good to be implemented, even if this situation is not very probable...

Comment: It works, But I tried without using `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible` and works also without any issue.

Comment: @user22 I know that, I recommended this way. But, in this case Excel makes a guess! It makes a good guess, supposing that you need the visible cells and returns them as range. Even if usually Excel makes good guesses, **this is not happening all the time**... |I am not referring to this specific case. That's why it is better/safer to supply a range representing your real need. Which is a range of visible cells. Of course, you may use the more compact version, I suggested in my comment, but the safer is the one I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Filtered Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()
 
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1:Q6880")
    ' If your range is contiguous (no empty rows or columns):
    'Dim rng As Range: Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim fcrg As Range: Set fcrg = rng.Columns(8) ' Filter Column Range
    ' Filter Column Data Range (no headers)
    Dim fcdrg As Range: Set fcdrg = fcrg.Resize(fcrg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    fcrg.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="0"
    
    Dim vfcdrg As Range ' Visible Filter Column Data Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vfcdrg = fcdrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    If vfcdrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no filtered values
    
    vfcdrg.EntireRow.Delete
 
End Sub
```

Comment: It works , But it remove all filters .also `Compile error: Variable not defined` with **frg** , I changed to **fcrg**

Comment: Corrected `fcrg`. After `On Error Goto 0`, Instead of `ws.AutoFilterMode = False`, use `ws.ShowAllData`.