# I need to delete visible rows using Macro except the header, but I keep encountering an error

Tags: excel, vba

[image: error]

here is the part of the code:

```
Sheets("Aging").Select
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("1200", "1301", "1302", "1303", "1304", "1305", 
"1306", "1307", "1308", "1309"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
rng.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<60"
rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Im trying to delete the visible rows (excluding the header) with the following criteria (for Field 6) then unfilter it. after that filter Field 11 and delete values less than 60.

[image]

Comment: What range do you select? I mean, how your initial `rng` look? Is it the header? Is it a selection of whole columns? Or, what?

Comment: I think, instead of the picture showing the error, it would be good to edit your question and place a picture with the processed sheet and selection in discussion as you make it...

Comment: Try to avoid using ActiveXXXXX.  The ActiveXXXXX is not always what you think it is.  Always, always always, use a qualifying reference to a known worksheet.

Comment: @freeflow His code first line activates the sheet in discussion. Which is not a good way of programming, but everything following that line refers `rng` as a selection in the active sheet. Anyhow, this looks to probably be the real problem... It depends on the selection meaning, to suggest a correct way of dealing with the obtained ranges after filtering, I also think.

Comment: @FaneDuru , I remembered that you helped me in such a similar case [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71066351/delete-visible-filtered-rows-run-time-error-1004cannot-use-that-command-on-ove)

Comment: @Waleed Yes, but your question was clearer in terms of range to be filtered. Now, not knowing what selection he does (exactly like in your last question... :)), I cannot suggest anything... I can make assumptions, I even tried to enumerate some possibilities in my clarification comment, but it should be his turn to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed selected the header(row) (which you should avoid to do, using Select(ion) I mean), and then use .Offset(1,0), you're on the row below that, even if that row is hidden due to the filter. If it's hidden, it can't be deleted when going for the visible cells.

In case you were using the header, you can use the following:

```
Sub deleteVisibleRows()
    Dim rng As Range, rngDel As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Aging")
    Dim lCol As Long, lRow As Long, lRowDel As Long
    
    With ws
        lCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, lCol))
    End With
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("1200", "1301", "1302", "1303", "1304", "1305", _
    "1306", "1307", "1308", "1309"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
    lRowDel = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRowDel > 1 Then 'to prevent error from when there are no rows to delete
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    ws.ShowAllData
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="<60"
    lRowDel = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If lRowDel > 1 Then ' same as before, you could use a msgbox to say there's nothing to delete if preferred
        rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(lRow - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    'If you wanted to keep the AutoFilter on, you can just use ws.ShowAllData again
End Sub
```

The `.Resize(lRow - 1)` makes sure you have your entire range selected and the `If` statements are there for when there's nothing to delete.
Hope this showed you how to avoid using `Select` and `ActiveSheet`, even if the header wasn't your selection, it should help you understand how to avoid trying to delete hidden rows.